# What's the point of the song "look at me, I'm Sandra Dee" in Grease?

Tags: character, reference, grease

This song looks to be a reference to the actress Sandra Dee, as if herself or the roles she played were that of an "innocent" grown up woman.

I'm not much an expert on what roles she played or who she was in real life, but from what I know it's not that their roles were of the type I'm mentioning and I doubt that at the time they'd get to know much about her life. So I cannot grasp the meaning on the song based on that.

What's the reason then? Or am I mistaken in my appreciation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie was based on a [musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grease_(musical)).  Yes, the musical came first and was then made into a movie.  In the original musical version, Olivia Newton John's character Sandy Olsson was named Sandy Dumbrowski.  They decided to change her name and her background to fit Olivia's after they cast her to star in the movie, so the changed her last name to a more Australian sounding one.

The song Look At me, I'm Sandra Dee makes references to several 50's personalities, including Doris Day, Annette Funacello and Elvis Presley.  Sandy Dumbrowski made for the perfect reference when shortened to Sandra Dee, the actress with the perfect image.